# Ruby 2.3.1 how to set the project root directory in config.rb

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rsolr

I have a project in Ruby 2.3.1 and I'm using at the moment absolute path to a folder where I'm having uploaded files. What I would like to use instead is a relative path.
I would like to know how to set in Ruby config.rb the root directory / so I could call when I need the relative path to a folder like
root_dir + '/public/files'

The project is a Ruby RESTFull API which works with Solr for index/search PDF files. The app is a custom app with Sinatra and Rsolr.
This API has an upload function which points to a folder.

My Upload script:

```
post '/api/uploads' do
  #puts params
  fns = params['files'].map {|f| f[:filename]}.join(";")
  param = fns.chomp.split(";")
  #find pdf files
  param.select! {|f| f =~ /.*\.pdf/}

  array_length = param.length # or $param.size

  puts "length of $param is : #{array_length}"

  if(array_length==0)
    raise( "files not pdf: #{fns}")
  end
  i = 0
  resp = []
  while i.to_i < array_length do
    puts i
    filename = params[:documents][i][:filename]
    tmpfile = params[:documents][i][:tempfile]
    target = settings.homedir+'/'+filename
    localpath = File.join(settings.filesdir, filename)
    File.open(localpath, 'wb') do |f|
      f.write tmpfile.read
    end

    resp << {:fileurl => target}
    i = i + 1
  end
```

My config.rb:

```
set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
    set :filesdir, 'absolute_path/public/documents/pdf' # Set pdf files folder absolute path
    set :homedir, '/pdf'                         # Set pdf home directory
    set :solrbase, 'http://localhost:8983/solr/' # Set Solr connection path
    set :solrcore, 'docs'                        # Set name of the Solr core


    set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
    set :port, 3003                              # Set port of the API

    set :show_exceptions, false

    configure do
        mime_type :pdf, 'application/pdf'
  end
```

I would like to not write the absolute path and get a relative path so for example, another developer can use it immediately without set again the absolute path.

Comment: Ruby is programming language. Are you asking about the Rails framework?

Comment: Only Ruby without the Rails part, I have to point to a folder which contains some files. @Max

Comment: "Only Ruby" doesn't have a `config.rb`. That's something custom to the project you are working on. You need to provide more information in the question.

Comment: Also, paths in Ruby work just like in a shell. Start the path with . and it will be relative.

Comment: Hi @Jakub. Have you seen the docs on [Configuring Settings](http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html)? Have a quick look (look out for the `:root` and `:public_folder` settings in particular) and see if that helps. If you still have problems just let me know. I also recommend a quick look at the [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) library, (a much underused one in my opinion), it's helpful with paths.